# Laravel: get complete path of file programatically?

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I have to put the whole path of my file, like this:

```
$credentialsFilePath = "C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp.com\json\myapp-dda63-firebase-adminsdk-a84ay-19eb8e8646.json"
```

However this doesn't look so good to me, in production I will have to change the string path for it to work.

Is there a laravel method to do something like this:

```
absolutePath().'/json/myapp-dda63-firebase-adminsdk-a84ay-19eb8e8646.json'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, you can use:

```
base_path()
```

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning that `base_path` accepts an argument to render a specific path so you do not need to concatenate `base_path().'/somewhere'`, in stead you can add the path as a param like so: `base_path('somewhere')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to create a variable in `php` file within the `config folder` and use that variable all over the applications.

###### Declare variable and set default path in config variable for Firebase:

```
'firebase_credentials' => env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS', base_path().'/json/myapp-dda63-firebase-adminsdk-a84ay-19eb8e8646.json'),
```

then use that variable using `config()` method all over the application. By using that syntax you can set variable value from `.env` file for different servers i.e. **staging, dev, prod**